# pod and service dns resolution

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networking

I have a kubernetes cluster on which I deployed pods and services.  One of the pod should connect to a service via the service name given its manifest.

All services and pods are deployed in the default namespace.

I have the following error in looking at the logs of the pod:

```
cassandra cluster ['cassandra'] not reachable: [Errno -8] Unrecognized service

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: cassandra: Name does not resolve
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.addContactPoint(Cluster.java:884)
```

I have a service deployed called cassandra.

When I run nslookup inside a pod here is the output:

```
kubectl exec -it pod/kairosdb -- nslookup cassandra
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Name:      cassandra
Address 1: <ip> cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Looking for some help on how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: This is looking for the name `cassandra`. Is there a service with this name in the same namespace? Can you lookup this name from one of your pods?

Comment: @BurakSerdar I updated the post to answer your question

Comment: Do you have a running dns in your cluster? Can you find other names?

Answer (score 1):

If the pod is trying to access a service which is located in a different namespace then you need to specify the namespace of the service.

```
cassandra.namespacename
```

See [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/) for more debugging help.

Answer (score 1):

For local lookup, use the the fully qualified service name. In this case, ***cassandra.deployed-namespace-name.svc.cluster.local***.